# Can I define a dependency for the `setup.py` script itself?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I have a project that depends on the [YouTokenToMe](https://github.com/VKCOM/YouTokenToMe) package. The `setup.py` of YouTokenToMe uses `Cython.Build.cythonize()` to generate the `ext_modules`.

This means that `pip install` in a new environment (without Cython installed) will fail even before it installs the `install_requires` modules (it fails on the first lines of `setup.py` when it tried to import Cython).

Is there a non-hacky solution to this? Can I define dependencies to the `setup.py` script itself? An obvious workaround is to just install Cython on the env before but I rather avoid it going forward..

Thanks!

Comment: Put the dependency in `setup_requires` if you have a setup script, or in the `requires` list under the `[build-system]` section in your `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: Thanks! But since the setup.py itself is importing Cython before anything else, adding it just to the setup() argument doesn't help (it crashes before running setup()). 
This project doesn't have pyproject.toml (a 3rd party), I'm trying to figure out what would be the best to do for now..